# How to make more secure forms

Tags: html, forms, security

I recently launched a new website, and in it, used the form code given to me from Salesforce.com so the form results go into that system.  Here is the code:

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <div id="email_signup"> 
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00000000000000">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.example.com/thank-you">                                 
    <input type="text" name="email" id="input_newsletter_email" maxlength="80" style="display:none;"/> 
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        <input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="company">Company</label>
        <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" required /><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="phone" /><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

We've been getting some spam signups like " Company:  nxlhfzxg, Lead Name:  rnsoniinqe rnsoniinqe"

There doesn't seem to be any purpose to these, but they are coming in frequently.

I added in the required attribute to email because I thought that might help, but it didn't.  They just started inputting random emails.

Do you know:

1. Why this would happen
2. What I can do to prevent it?  Is Wufoo a good choice?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered adding a captcha?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to see if there are any other options as well.  We are just a small company and this is basically a contact form, so I don't want to encumber the lead generation process if I can help it.

Comment: Since you're a small company, why not use some javascript to make the user do a basic math problem. It would be much simpler then implementing the captcha and a lot less of a nuisance for the sender

Answer (score 2):

This happens because it is trivial to write a script that submits this type of form.

What can you do:

> 1)  Implement CAPTCHA
>    2)  Implement a question a human can easily
>   answer: i.e. what is the color of the sky
>     3)  Use a simple email
>   regex checker( just validate that it has an `@` and a `.`), this stops
>   a surprising number of these requests.

Comment: Make sure the question is sufficiently random so that the script doesn't get the same question more than once

Comment: @Freedom_Ben right where sufficient is some arbitrary boundary for what your application needs, so yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to screen IPs from spammers using some of the [known spam lists](http://spam-ip.com/).  When someone spams you, add their IP to the list.